# Can I Hide the Mouse Pointer for a Dropdown Option with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I can hide the mouse pointer for an element by setting `cursor: none;` in CSS. However, this doesn't seem to work for `<select>`/`<option>` dropdown inputs. See the gif below. The pointer is hidden for the input element, but not for the actual dropdown part.

[image]

I tried setting `cursor: none;` for both the `<select>` element and the `<option>` elements, but it didn't work. Is there any way to hide the mouse pointer on a dropdown menu?